# Adding funds to Metaplex BundlrStorageDriver

Tags: metaplex, nft, bundlr

I am building an app that allows you to upload a photo and mint it as an NFT on Solana. I am trying to add funds to a BundlrStorageDriver object like this:

```
const storage = metaplex.storage().driver() as BundlrStorageDriver;
storage.fund(1000)
```

Which should work according to this [documentation](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#MetaplexFile).

[image]

But I am getting this error:
[image]

I looked online and couldn't find any references to BundlrStorageDriver's native functions or the data type 'Amount', so not sure how to proceed from here. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried this and it worked. (await storage.bundlr()).fund(1000);. Gonna go forward with that for now!

Comment: Better to post resolutions as an answer than a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition for the `Amount` structure and friends,

```
export type Amount<T extends Currency = Currency> = {
  basisPoints: BigNumber;
  currency: T;
};

export type Currency = {
  symbol: string;
  decimals: number;
  namespace?: 'spl-token';
};

export type SplTokenCurrency = {
  symbol: string;
  decimals: number;
  namespace: 'spl-token';
};
export type SplTokenAmount = Amount<SplTokenCurrency>;

export const SOL = {
  symbol: 'SOL',
  decimals: 9,
} as const;
export type SolCurrency = typeof SOL;
export type SolAmount = Amount<SolCurrency>;
```

Looks like  it's just a wrapper to indicate if you are funding in SOL or with other SPL-tokens (looks like they at least support USDC).

So the correct way of calling the fund function while funding with SOL should be:

```
const amount: SolAmount = {
    basisPoints: new BigNumber(2000),
    currency: SOL
};
await (await bundlrStorage.bundlr()).fund(amount);
```

It should be noted that `BigNumber` doesn't come from the `bignumber.js` library, which is common, It is instead a type inside the same Metaplex library.